# Reporting for Python tests built using PyUnit

Tags: selenium, python, test-report

I am looking for a good reporting tool for Python tests-specifically the one which supports Python 3.0+, with Selenium, built using the default `PyUnit` framework.

So far I have come across only one tool, which is

- [HTMLRunner](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/HTMLTestRunner)

But it doesn't serves the purpose, since it doesn't supports Python 3.0+ (I tried the GIT repository but return empty handed). I am trying to port the code to Python 3.0, but I want an option in case I fail (or time constraints come in to play).

Another option is [Allure](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki), but since it supports only `PyTest`, I am not able to use it.

Does anybody has used any other tool other than this. Please suggest.

Comment: Did you try Nose? It supports Python 3.x: https://github.com/nose-devs/nose, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138311/python-unittest-reporting-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some deliberations and code changes (not much), I was able to port the HTMLRunnner code to Python 3.0+ compatible mode.

I ran a simple test suite using the HTMLRunner and I can see an HTML report created out of it. It's not as fancy as Allure but it does the job.

Another option suggested by @Amazpyel is Nose, although I haven't tried it out yet.

If any body wants to use the HTMLRunner Python 3.0+ code, here it is in my GIT : [HTMLRunner](https://github.com/zac11/HTMLRunner)